# Unable get the date of each facebook like Using facebook4j

Tags: java

Trying to get the date of each facebook like using facebook4j:
using the following code :

```
ResponseList<Reaction> reacts = facebook.getPostReactions(postId);
for (Reaction react : reacts) {
System.out.println(react);
}
```

but it returns the object with without the date
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, facebook4j doesn't support createdDate for likes for now